# Can phonegap coding on Windows and building on Mac for iOS be simplified without remote building?

Tags: cordova

Scenario:
I'm developing a phonegap app on Windows but have to build on Mac.
Why I'm developing on Windows: I simply don't like OS X's look, feel, usability and so on.

So I do share my code via Mercurial which works fine.
On the mac via CLI I generate the XCode project.

My problem:
Everytime I generate the XCode project, the source files for the plugins I'm using are gone and I have to add them manually in XCode.
Beside that I have to restore code modifications every time as well. (for example removing iOS 7's status bar)

Does anybody know any best practices for this kind of setup?
Or is this just the pitfall for not using Phonegap's remote building feature, which (of course) isn't free?

Best regards

Comment: Which folders do you share via Mercurial?

Comment: right now all but platform - I've had some problems with that folder running mercurial in the past.

Comment: If you added the platform folder after you have installed the plugins you could try to delete and reinstall them. Maybe they are not under version control right now.